# What is cooking.SE's policy on "List of X" questions?

Tags: discussion

I am exploring the world of self-made pasta at the moment.

My first experiments, doing everything entirely by hand, show that if you want to do this on a frequent basis and not just as a one-time thing, you need *tools*.

I can see a number of pasta making tools on the market: Sieves, rolling mechanisms of various complexity, etc. A lot of them look like crap that's going to break after the third use, and a lot exceed my budget.

I am therefore tempted to ask a generic "what tools and instruments are there for making Pasta?" question and mark it Community Wiki, in the hopes of gathering a lot of input and discovering something simple and affordable I've not yet thought of.

Will this work?

Any thoughts?

> **Update**: I've posted the question [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7833/tools-for-making-pasta).

Answer (score 1):

I think that would be fine, as long as you make it CW (since there won't be a "correct" answer). Generic equipment discussion is definitely on topic. What might get off topic is discussion of a particular make / model of a piece of equipment. So discussion of Blenders is ok, but Blend-tec 1000 v3 would be off topic. Keep that in mind and you should be fine (doesn't sound like your question will tread that territory anyway).

Comment: Sounds great, cheers! I will definitely want to stay in the generic field.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is intended to gather a *list* of relevant answers, and you don't expect one answer to be the most applicable, it should be a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

Whether a subjective question is appropriate for the site is somewhat, well... subjective.  The "guidelines" at the bottom of this blog post provides some criteria to help:

[**Good Subjective, Bad Subjective**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Answer (score 0):

Even though you want to stay in the generic field, make sure to indicate *what you are expecting from the piece of equipment*; what is essential, and what is not essential. It will provide you with a better compendium that is specific to your answer while laying out what makes the different pieces valuable.

Even after you have bought your machine, people who may be cruising cooking.SE since they're in the market for the same will understand better what criteria they might consider, what factors into the cost, and will learn more about the different features.